# Eclipse plugins for Java EE development

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee, eclipse-plugin

What it is the best combination for fast development Java EE projects in Eclipse.
What i try to get is

- Fast application server start
- Hot deploy in both web-app and ejb modules.
- Editing jsp without server restart

I found out for myself that best choice when developing webapp application is using WTP for Eclipse with maven plugin.
It give me all feature of WTP and also provide with up-to-date building script, that can be used outside of Eclipse, and also it simplify jar management.

I'm looking for something similar when developing Java EE application. What is the best combination of Java EE server(should i use Jboss or Glassfish) and Eclipse plugins ?

Comment: What exactly are you missing in Eclipse for Java EE Developers? I'm quite happy with it and some additional plugins.

Answer (score 2):

WTP is completely sufficient:

- it allows you to start and stop servers and redeploy applications (see the `Servers` view)
- allows hot swap - i.e. replace the class on save (unless you have made structural changes) (just start the server in debug mode)
- jsp pages can be edited without restart with default configuration of most servlet containers.